# Lock screen orientation to just one landscape and one portrait modes

Tags: android, orientation, landscape, portrait

Let's say my app has two activities `A` and `B`. And, also, let's call the posible screen orientations `landscape-1`, `portrait-2`, `landscape-3` and `portrait-4`.
I would like to lock the orientation of `A` to landscape (`1` and `3`), and `B` to both landscape and portrait (`1`, `2`, `3` and `4`).
So, to do this, I used `sensorLandscape`. Later I realized that `sensorLandscape` is for API 9 or greater, and I want to support older versions. I searched for a way to emulate `sensorLandscape` behaviour, but I didn't find anything. So I'm now going for a simpler approach: I would like to use `landscape` mode on activity `A` (this is, just `1`), but I don't want the user to be able to use `landscape-3` on activity `B` (so there's no weird turning when going back to activity `A`).
**To sum up**, the idea is the following:
Posible screen orientations for activity `A`: `landscape-1`.
Posible screen orientations for activity `B`: `landscape-1` and `portrait-3`.
Any ideas on how to accomplish this behaviour?

Comment: Forcing orientation lock for Activity B is pointless and will possibly cause user annoyance. If you're going to support landscape & portrait for Activity B then just let the user decide which orientation they want (landscape, inverse landscape, portrait, inverse portrait).- in other words don't try to lock orientation at all. As for Activity A, again you could cause user annoyance if you only support one landscape mode - fine, force landscape-only orientation if you need to but support both landscape and inverse landscape.

Comment: I would love to do that, that's what `sensorLandscape` does. But I can't use it because I need to support older devices. Do you know how can I emulate `sensorLandscape` behaviour?

Comment: Look in to setting orientation dynamically in your Activity code. Check for API version and then set orientation depending on that - if the API > 9 then you should be able to detect current device orientation. Activity B can (and should) be allowed to do its own thing automatically adjusted by the OS and actual device orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Use it and don't support api <13 just because no need to make extra work

Done is better than perfect

Don't worry you are still targeting 97% of Android Users with Api >=9.

Comment: I can't afford that. In my country, many people use cellphones with lower APIs.

Comment: You don't write apps for the people of your country but for the world...I can't imagine that there are many users in your country with a pis lower than Android 4.0

Comment: But a workaround would be to use the sensor manager and ask the force of the  x and y axis

Comment: It's for a strictly local use. The app is not intended to the whole world, it would make no sense.  Can you elaborate on that workaround?